# concatenate two variables in react

Tags: reactjs, concatenation

I am currently mapping over data, and I want to concatenate 2 variables together.

For example:

```
<img src={image path}{image name from .map} />
```

So the question is, how do i combine these both into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are a lot of ways to do it, one could be with string literals interpolation:

```
<img src={`${variable1}${variable2}`}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

use back tack for example

```
<img src={`${image path}${image name from .map}`} />
```